# Determining if batch script has been started/executed from the command line (cmd) -or- To pause or not to pause?

Tags: windows, cmd, batch-file

I like to have a typical "usage:" line in my `cmd.exe` scripts — if a parameter is missing, user is given simple reminder of how the script is to be used.

The problem is that I can't safely predict whether potential user would use GUI or CLI. If somebody using GUI double-clicks this script in Explorer window, they won't have chance to read anything, unless I `pause` the window. If they use CLI, `pause` will bother them.

So I'm looking for a way to detect it.

```
@echo off
if _%1_==__ (
    echo usage: %nx0: filename
    rem now pause or not to pause?
)
```

Is there a nice solution on this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can check the value of `%CMDCMDLINE%` variable. It contains the command that was used to launch `cmd.exe`.

I prepared a test .bat file:

```
@Echo Off
echo %CMDCMDLINE%
pause
```

When run from inside of open `cmd.exe` window, the script prints `"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe"`.
When run by double-clicking, it prints `cmd /c ""C:\Users\mbu\Desktop\test.bat" "`

So to check if your script was launched by double-clicking you need to check if `%cmdcmdline%` contains the path to your script. The final solution would look like this:

```
@echo off

set interactive=1
echo %cmdcmdline% | find /i "%~0" >nul
if not errorlevel 1 set interactive=0

rem now I can use %interactive% anywhere

if _%1_==__ (
    echo usage: %~nx0 filename
    if _%interactive%_==_0_ pause
)
```

**Edit:** implemented fixes for issues changes discussed in comments; edited example to demonstrate them

Comment: Strange enough: if you open new cmd.exe session and call this, the first time it pauses: it seems that `find` does not raise `%errorlevel%` in the first attempt. Next and other attempts are fine.

Comment: The raising of `%errorlevel%` also fails if other commands (typical couple of `set`s and a `cd` in my case) are present *before* this construct.

Comment: Plus, this won't work in a subroutine called using `call :somesub`. In that case `%cmdcmdline%` will contain only label of that subroutine: `%cmdcmdline%`.

Comment: However the discrepancies I describe are in fact discrepancies of `cmd.exe` and Windows. The solution is pretty neat (+1) and unless somebody will come up with something else in few days, I will accept it.

Comment: Try changing `if %errorlevel%==0` to `if not errorlevel 1`. It seems it gives more reliable results, for me it does not pause in a fresh opened `cmd.exe` window. Another thing worth trying is executing this at the beginning of the script and storing result in a variable.

Comment: yes, implementing both your tips seems to solve both issues: now after the `find`, I just `if not errorlevel 1 set interactive=0` (no need to have it as first command) and then I can use `%interactive%` wherever I need to, including any number of routines. can I accept twice? .-)

Comment: Thanks for editing the answer! I was going to do it myself, but you were faster :-)

Comment: I just experienced another issue with using cmdcmdline: It contains the whole call, pipes and ampersands and all. So if I call my script with any sideeffects, like `test.bat && TestSucceeded.bat` or anything like that, these are executed when cmdcmdline is referenced. And in this case, the output of TestSucceeded.bat will probably be piped into find. It should help removing such operators with `echo %cmdcmdline:&|<>=% | find ...`

Comment: Hm, for some reason the string replacement I did (which is totally wrong here and does not work, I'm ashamed I posted it...) worked in the script I tried it in. Very strange. Still looking for reliable fix.

Answer (score 5):

```
:: exit if not interactive
echo %CMDCMDLINE% | find /i "/c"
if not ERRORLEVEL 1 goto:eof
```

Comment: could you elaborate more on how this differs from the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here, I wrote something...

`Usage.bat`

---

```
@echo off
if arg%1==arg goto help
goto action

:action
echo do something...
goto end

:help
set help1=This is Help line 1.
set help2=This is Help line 2.
cmd.exe /k "echo %help1% &echo %help2%"
goto end

:end
```

---

It's not perfect, but it works! :D

-joedf

Answer (score 1):

This is only using the internal command. so effectively....

> EnableDelayedExpansion

```
if "!cmdcmdline!" neq "!cmdcmdline:%~f0=!" pause >nul
```

or

```
if not "!cmdcmdline!" == "!cmdcmdline:%~f0=!" pause >nul
```

> DisableDelayedExpansion

```
if "%cmdcmdline%" neq "%cmdcmdline:%~f0=%" pause >nul
```

or

```
if not "%cmdcmdline%" == "%cmdcmdline:%~f0=%" pause >nul
```

Answer (score 1):

Start your batch checking for %WINDIR% in %cmdcmdline% like this:

```
echo "%cmdcmdline%" | findstr /ic:"%windir%" >nul && (
  echo Interactive run of: %0 is not allowed
  pause
  exit /B 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use **findstr**

```
echo %cmdcmdline% | findstr /ic:"%~f0" >nul && ( pause >nul )
```

or

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
.
.
echo !cmdcmdline! | findstr /ic:"%~f0" >nul && ( pause >nul )
.
.
endlocal
```

This is always worked...

Comment: Well, *findstr* is an external program, so it's not really "from within", but yes, a viable option.

Comment: find.exe findstr.exe - these are windows internal exe. that is similar with internal command.

Answer (score 0):

for internal command

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "cmddiff=!cmdcmdline:~0,1!" & if !cmddiff! neq ^" ( pause >nul )
endlocal
```

or

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "cmddiff=!cmdcmdline:~28,1!" & if !cmddiff! neq ^" ( pause >nul )
endlocal
```

You can compare the different thing, but this is only worked within EnableDelayedExpansion. and I don't think that this will be always worked, cause windows version, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Similar approach...

```
setlocal

set startedFromExplorer=
echo %cmdcmdline% | find /i "cmd.exe /c """"%~0""" >nul
if not errorlevel 1 set startedFromExplorer=1

...

if defined startedFromExplorer pause
goto :EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

if "!cmdcmdline!" neq "!cmdcmdline:%comspec%=!" ( pause>nul )
```

Test is done in Windows 10. Using %windir%, it is a little dangerous or ambiguous. So %comspec% is super safe.