# How can I call a batch script from another batch script without pausing at the end?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, cmd

I have a batch script that copies a directory to a backup drive:

```
@echo off
robocopy c:\somefolder d:\backup /mir
pause
```

The reason for the pause at the end is sometimes I like to review the results of the copy operation before I close it.

I have another batch script that calls my backup script and then shuts down the computer:

```
@echo off
call backup.bat > nul
echo "Press any key to shutdown . . ."
pause > nul
shutdown /s /t 00
```

The problem is the command prompt just sits after it calls backup.bat because of the pause at the end. I can remove `> nul` from the second line, but I don't want to see the results of the copy operation when I run *this* script. I just want this script to call the other one and then prompt me before shutting down the computer. How do I do that?

Comment: You want to detect in backup.bat if it was run from other script or not.  Check out my [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419875/determining-if-the-batch-script-has-been-executed-from-the-command-line-or-to) on how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pipe whatever to the call

```
cd . | call backup.bat > nul
```

**Edited** as it seems something in the process will not allow to supress the `pause` with a redirection (but in my PC it works :-? ), the better way to handle it pass a parameter to the `backup.bat` to determine if it needs to wait or not

*backup.bat*

```
@echo off
robocopy c:\somefolder d:\backup /mir
if /i not "%~1"=="nopause" pause
```

And the call from the other script will be

```
call backup.bat nopause > nul
```

Comment: ERROR: Input redirection is not supported, exiting the process immediately. :(

Comment: @Koveras, at this moment, i don't know why it fails for you but not for me (something more to test :) ). Answer updated. Hope it will work for you